# Ionic2, Http request don´t work correctly in starting page

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic2, httprequest, ionic2-providers

I created a simple app (sidemenu template) and a provider (conexao-home.ts). In a new page called teste i created a function buscarUsuarios (associated a one button), and it calls the function getRemoteUsers in provider.

In ionViewDidLoad i put the same call to function getRemoteUsers.
When the page teste starts, it makes the the call to function and read data from http, but don´t return in the back variable data read.
When i make the call from button, it returns the data from the first read and show it in the page.

How to solve this?

teste.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ConexaoHome } from '../../providers/conexao-home';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-teste',
  templateUrl: 'teste.html',
})
export class Teste {

  public users: any;
  public teste: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public conexaoServico: ConexaoHome) {

  }

  buscarUsuarios() {
    this.users = this.conexaoServico.getRemoteUsers('Pegando os usuários');
    console.log('chamando...');
    console.log(this.users);
    console.log('retornando...' + this.users);
  }

  buscar() {
    this.teste = this.conexaoServico.getRemoteTeste('testando...');
    console.log(this.teste);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Teste');
    //this.buscarUsuarios();
    this.users = this.conexaoServico.getRemoteUsers('Pegando os usuários');
    console.log(this.users);
  }

}
```

teste.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Teste</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding="false">
  <button ion-button (click)="buscarUsuarios()">Pegar Dados</button>
  <br>
  <button ion-button (click)="buscar()">Pegar Dados 2</button>
  {{ teste }}
  <br>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="{{ user.picture.medium }}">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2 text-wrap>{{ user.name.title }} {{ user.name.first }} {{ user.name.last }}</h2>
      <h3 text-wrap>{{ user.email }}</h3>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

provider conexao-home.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ConexaoHome {

  public usuarios: any;
  public areas: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello ConexaoHome Provider');
  }

  getRemoteUsers(tipo) {
    this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10').
    map(res => res.json()
    ).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.results);
      console.log(tipo);
      this.usuarios = data.results;
    });
    return this.usuarios;
  }

  getRemoteTeste(tipo) {
    console.log(tipo);
    return ('teste executado 2');
  }
}
```

Tks.

Comment: Using Ionic V 2.2.3

Comment: you can try with ionic 3.x with answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800643/where-to-add-rest-api-consuming-functionality-in-ionic-framework-3-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do like that:

```
getRemoteUsers(tipo) {
    this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10').
    map(res => res.json()
    ).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.results);
      console.log(tipo);
      this.usuarios = data.results;
    });
    return this.usuarios;
}
```

That could finish return statement before async call has finished. Because you made an asynchronous http request via Observable. You should read more about that [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript#getting-data-from-ajax-requests)

Instead please try something like this:

```
getRemoteUsers(tipo) {
    return this.http
      .get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
      .map(res => res.json())
}
```

Then you should use it like this:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.conexaoServico.getRemoteUsers('Pegando os usuários').subscribe((data) => { 
       this.users = data;
       console.log(this.users);
    });
}
```

Comment: Its works now, thanks. I have developed in Ionic 1 and now i´m learning Ionic 2, so i don´t have used observable until now. I will read the link you send. Thanks again.